# Dash output with multiple inputs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to have a dash component properly input variables and give appropriate output.

Currently multiple inputs will make the functionality not work.

I've put multi=true for my dcc dropdown - hasn't worked successfully yet.

This is the code I have used.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd

import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_excel('FreewayFDSData.xlsx', 'Volume', parse_dates=True, index_col="Time")
df = df.T

Detectors = list(df.columns)

mf = pd.read_excel('FreewayFDSData.xlsx', 'Coordinates')

mapbox_access_token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'

#  Layouts

layout_map = dict(
    autosize=True,
    height=500,
    font=dict(color="#191A1A"),
    titlefont=dict(color="#191A1A", size='18'),
    margin=dict(
        l=35,
        r=35,
        b=35,
        t=45
    ),
    hovermode="closest",
    plot_bgcolor='#fffcfc',
    paper_bgcolor='#fffcfc',
    legend=dict(font=dict(size=10), orientation='h'),
    title='Freeway detectors',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        style="light",
        center=dict(
            lon=145.061,
            lat=-37.865
        ),
        zoom=12,
    )
)


def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]

        #Styling

    )


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    html.H1(children='Managed Motorway'),

    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='xaxis-column',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in Detectors],
                value='Volume per 15 seconds',
                style={"width" : '48%'}
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='xaxis-type',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                value='Linear',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
            )
        ]),
        dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic'),
        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph',
            figure={
                'data': [{
                    'lat': mf.Y, 'lon': mf.X, 'type': 'scattermapbox'
                }],
                'layout': layout_map
            }
        )
    ], style={'display': 'block'}),

    html.Div([
    html.H4(children='Example of Freeway FDS Data'),
        html.Div([
        generate_table(df)
    ], style={'overflowX': 'scroll','overflowY': 'scroll', 'width':'48%','height':'300px'})
])
])


@app.callback(
    Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('xaxis-column', 'value'),
     Input('xaxis-type', 'value')])

def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, xaxis_type):
    # xaxis column name will assign the x axis data being sought
    return {
        'data': [go.Scatter(
            x=df.index,
            y=df[xaxis_column_name])]
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is an example of the data being inputted.

```
Time    00:00 - 00:15   00:15 - 00:30   00:30 - 00:45   00:45 - 01:00   01:00 - 01:15   01:15 - 01:30   01:30 - 01:45   01:45 - 02:00   02:00 - 02:15   02:15 - 02:30   02:30 - 02:45   02:45 - 03:00   03:00 - 03:15   03:15 - 03:30   03:30 - 03:45   03:45 - 04:00   04:00 - 04:15   04:15 - 04:30   04:30 - 04:45   04:45 - 05:00   05:00 - 05:15   05:15 - 05:30   05:30 - 05:45   05:45 - 06:00   06:00 - 06:15   06:15 - 06:30   06:30 - 06:45   06:45 - 07:00   07:00 - 07:15   07:15 - 07:30   07:30 - 07:45   07:45 - 08:00   08:00 - 08:15   08:15 - 08:30   08:30 - 08:45   08:45 - 09:00   09:00 - 09:15   09:15 - 09:30   09:30 - 09:45   09:45 - 10:00   10:00 - 10:15   10:15 - 10:30   10:30 - 10:45   10:45 - 11:00   11:00 - 11:15   11:15 - 11:30   11:30 - 11:45   11:45 - 12:00   12:00 - 12:15   12:15 - 12:30   12:30 - 12:45   12:45 - 13:00   13:00 - 13:15   13:15 - 13:30   13:30 - 13:45   13:45 - 14:00   14:00 - 14:15   14:15 - 14:30   14:30 - 14:45   14:45 - 15:00   15:00 - 15:15   15:15 - 15:30   15:30 - 15:45   15:45 - 16:00   16:00 - 16:15   16:15 - 16:30   16:30 - 16:45   16:45 - 17:00   17:00 - 17:15   17:15 - 17:30   17:30 - 17:45   17:45 - 18:00   18:00 - 18:15   18:15 - 18:30   18:30 - 18:45   18:45 - 19:00   19:00 - 19:15   19:15 - 19:30   19:30 - 19:45   19:45 - 20:00   20:00 - 20:15   20:15 - 20:30   20:30 - 20:45   20:45 - 21:00   21:00 - 21:15   21:15 - 21:30   21:30 - 21:45   21:45 - 22:00   22:00 - 22:15   22:15 - 22:30   22:30 - 22:45   22:45 - 23:00   23:00 - 23:15   23:15 - 23:30   23:30 - 23:45   23:45 - 24:00
3674S_P1    88  116 84  68  76  56  56  48  72  48  76  40  76  44  36  76  76  116 124 176 236 352 440 624 1016    1172    1260    1280    1304    1312    1252    1344    1324    1336    1212    1148    1132    1120    1084    996 924 1040    952 900 900 1116    1136    1044    1144    1152    1224    1088    1132    1184    1208    1120    1240    1196    1116    1264    1196    1240    1308    1192    1164    1096    1080    1160    1112    1244    1244    1184    1232    996 1108    876 864 776 644 520 684 724 632 620 680 724 516 504 432 396 264 252 272 256 100 144
3674S_P0    88  116 76  68  76  56  56  48  68  48  76  48  80  44  32  76  76  108 120 180 240 340 456 624 1088    1268    1352    1384    1412    1376    1356    1372    1400    1436    1296    1240    1200    1256    1120    1028    1008    1072    980 944 932 1148    1192    1040    1188    1220    1292    1140    1116    1268    1292    1172    1272    1236    1216    1280    1248    1280    1388    1244    1224    1076    1096    1148    1108    1256    1356    1308    1236    992 1100    880 872 768 640 520 680 720 636 620 660 716 512 504 428 396 260 244 272 252 100 136
```

The end result is a bug with the output where instead of line graphs the base variable is changed.

Any help on fixing this issue is much appreciated (and if you're able to make my code less convulted I'd appreciate it.

Cheers!

Finished code with debug complete

```
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, xaxis_type):
    graph = []

    if xaxis_column_name != None :
        for i in range(0, len(xaxis_column_name)):
            graph_obj = go.Scatter(
                x=df.index,
                y=df[xaxis_column_name[i]])

            graph.append(graph_obj)
        return {
            'data': graph
        }
    return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to fully run your code to debug it well, I found this after a quick glance.

When the `xaxis-column` `Dropdown` component is changed to do a multi-select, it will return a `list` rather than a `value`, so the callback you have for `xaxis-column` will be erroneous,

Changing the callback to something like this should work,

```
@app.callback(
    Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('xaxis-column', 'value'),
     Input('xaxis-type', 'value')])

def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, xaxis_type):
    graph = []
    for i in range(0, len(xaxis_column_name)):
        graph_obj = go.Scatter(
            x=df.index,
            y=df[xaxis_column_name[i]])

        graph.append(graph_obj)
    return {
        'data': graph
    }
```

Comment: I've changed the input data so it should be easier to debug for you

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() - getting some small errors with graph appending onto an intial value, or if i remove the value then len is equal to 0 at start which also breaks the thing